# Who can explain the result?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Bank {
    private  int sum=0;

    public void add(int n) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sum+= n;

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}


public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    Bank bank = new Bank();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            bank.add(100);
        } 
    }
}

public class Tes2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(consumer);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(consumer);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

This is a multithreaded program, simulation is multiple depositors to the bank to deposit money, used to demonstrate multithreaded security issues.Since the code is not synchronized, its first and second results might be 200/200,200/300, and so on.But I don't understand why you get 100/100, who can explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a race condition.

Both threads have access to sum.

sum += n; is not atomic

Thread 1 reads sum 0

Thread 2 swaps in because the code isnt synchronized reads sum as 0

Thread 1 adds 100 to 0 and writes that to sum

Thread 2 adds 100 to 0 and writes that to sum overwriting thread 1s value

Comment: And the solution is either to use proper synchronization, or more simply to use AtomicInteger.

Comment: Thanks,Cwrwhaf! I get the point sum+=n; is not atomic.I thought  it was! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

If you think about the concurrency of this program just based on the lines in the code, the 100/100 output result wouldn't make sense. But you also have to think about what instructions are actually happening when these lines are being performed. Each line of code can consist of many, many assembly instructions. In this case, to add `n` to `sum`, what really happens is that the value of `sum` is read from memory, probably loaded onto a register, incremented, then re-written onto memory.

The 100/100 output can happen in the following scenario. Let's say thread 1 and thread 2 both call `bank.add(100)`, and the bank handles requests asynchronously. That is, the bank has a thread handling each request.

Then, thread 1 of the bank loads the value of `sum`, which is zero. Thread 2 also loads the value of `sum` right after, which is still zero. Then, thread 1 takes the value it loaded, adds `n=100`, and writes it into memory. Thread 2 does the same; it takes the value of sum it loaded previously, 0, adds 100, then writes it back onto memory. Then, they each print out the value of 100.